# Ptrace read errno value in child process

Tags: c, system-calls, errno, strace, ptrace

How does strace get errno from failed system calls in the process it traces?

For example, if I do `strace ls`, strace displays the symbolic errno value (e.g. `ENOENT`) when a call fails. I know that strace uses ptrace under the hood.

If I am using ptrace to trace a processes system calls, how can I read the value of errno in the traced process?

More specifically, how do I get the address of errno in the child process, so that I can read it using `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` or `process_vm_readv`?

Thanks

Comment: [`errno` is a C concept](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/09/23/) (and a per-thread variable at that), not a system concept. The value placed in `errno` is the negation of the value returned by the syscall. That is why [this](https://gist.github.com/303248153/30d72a91e116240251af3e7a5ff71d05) reads RAX and why [this](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2018/06/23/) sets RAX (when overriding a syscall).

Comment: I see my mistake: the strace output indicates that the system call returns -1, but I presumed that -1 is also returned in `rax`, but that is not the case. The program I have written also correctly shows that `rax` is the negation of `errno`. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to post an answer. I'm way too tired, and you apparently have working code you could share :)

Answer (score 1):

Following the system call, you'll need to get the registers, specifically `rax`. If the system call failed then the value for `rax` will be a high number such as `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF4`. `errno` is calculated by negating this number like so:

`-0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF4 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF - 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF4 + 1 = 0xC = 12`

Once you have `errno`, you can look it up in `errno.h`. The location is a bit different on different systems; if you're having trouble finding it you can run `echo "#include <errno.h>" | gcc -E -`, which will print out the location. In this example the error is `ENOMEM`.